How flip section in List control?
I created list witch elements loads from bottom to top. (Reversed List)
All works very well except Sections. When section fliped, header of section is still on bottom. I want section header move to Up and under section can be cells.

        VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(messagesViewModel.processedMessages, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section.date.relativeFormat!)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    ) {
                        ForEach(section.messages, id: \.self) { item in
                                                   SUIMessageCell(data: item, avatar: messagesViewModel.metaData!.av96, viewModel: messagesViewModel)
                                                       .listRowInsets(.init(top: 2, leading: 24, bottom: 2, trailing: 24))
                                                       .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor(hexString: "#F2F3F4")))
                                                       .modify {
                                                           if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                                                               $0.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                               }
                    }
                    .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))
                    .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
                    
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))
        .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 8)
        .background(Color(UIColor(hexString: "#F2F3F4")))
        
        SUIMessagesInputView(messageViewModel: messagesViewModel)
    }

